# passing std::plus as an argument

Tags: c++, templates

How do I pass std::plus as an argument across functions?

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

template < class T, typename F >
T fn(T a, T b, F f)
{
        return f<T>()(a,b);
}

template<class T>
struct X
{
    template < typename F>
    T foo(T a, T b, F f)
    {
        return fn<T, F>(a,b,f);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    X<int> f;
    std::cout<< f.foo(a,b, std::plus<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/g5NZc2x9V

main.cpp:7:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass `std::plus` as a runtime argument you have to actually construct one.

You can't pass a type as an argument. Trying to pass a naked `std::plus<int>` is akin to writing a class name or type name there i.e. you would not expect `foo(a,b, int)` to compile if it expects the third argument to be an int *value*.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template < class T, typename F >
T fn(T a, T b, F f)
{
    return f(a, b);
}

template<class T>
struct X
{
    template < typename F>
    T foo(T a, T b, F f)
    {
        return fn<T, F>(a, b, f);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    X<int> f;
    std::cout << f.foo(a, b, std::plus<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
std::cout<< f.foo(a,b, std::plus<int>);
```

`std::plus<int>` is a type. Just like `int`. This fails for the exact same reason the following code would fail to compile, too:

```
void function(int n)
{
}

void another_function()
{
    function(int);
}
```

You can't "pass `std::plus` as an argument" for the same exact reason you can't pass `int` as an argument.

What you can do, though -- and what you ***should*** do --- is to ***construct an instance*** of `std::plus`:

```
std::cout<< f.foo(a,b, std::plus<int>{});
```

Now, this passes an actual object, `std::plus<int>` to this function. However this is not going to be sufficient:

```
T fn(T a, T b, F f)
{
        return f<T>()(a,b);
}
```

Here, `f` is going to be that `std::plus<int>` object. It is a callable object, so, well, all you have to do is call it:

```
T fn(T a, T b, F f)
{
        return f(a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::plus<int>` is a type, not an object or function. So you cannot pass it to a function. You can however create an object of that type and pass that:

```
std::cout<< f.foo(a,b, std::plus<int>{});
```

Then in the call

```
return f<T>()(a,b);
```

the template arguments and first `()` make no sense. `f` is not a template, it is an object whose `operator()` you want to call, so:

```
return f(a,b);
```